# Crontab doesn't work at reboot

Tags: cron, reboot

I am using crontab on raspberry pi with raspbian. I edited the crontab file (`crontab -e`) so that now when I do `crontab -l`, it gives me `@reboot chromium-browser` as output. When I reboot, nothing happens. It doesn't even open a terminal... what could it be?

Comment: You normally can't start a GUI program via cron, and almost certainly not at reboot - cron might start long before the GUI/windowing system is running

Comment: I also tried with a simple echo and any other command...

Comment: But how do you determine that it did not work ? cron runs stuff in the background, you most certainly would not see any output of `echo` on your screen anywhere.

Comment: @nos Yeah I was suspecting that... Can I make it run in a terminal? Can set up crontab in a way that it opens a terminal and runs a command?

Comment: Not really. If you want to e.g. automatically boot into a desktop environment and auto-start certain applications, I suggest you ask a question about how to do that instead. There are many ways to do that that does not involve cron. cron is not suitable for launching GUI applications on boot. Remember to carefully specify which desktop/gui environment you are using, and ask it at superuser.com or raspberrypi.stackexchange.com, since stackoverflow.com is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your @reboot line to output an error log:

```
@reboot chromium-browser >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

You may need to create a small bash script that will actually perform the opening operation.

Comment: Ok and if once rebooted nothing happens I go to home/pi/logs/cronlog and check the log?